# Capabilities of Facebook permission offline_access?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Reading the Facebook documentation, I know that with the 'offline_access' permission it

> "Enables your app to perform authorized requests on behalf of the user at any time".

So, what types of requests can be made using this permission?

In my application, users can create custom images and share them with friends. But, I want to put their submissions into a moderation system. I'd like to have the user select friends to share, then after the moderator approves, post on the selected friends wall. Will 'offline_access' make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `offline_access` permission itself will **NOT** allow your app to *post* on behalf of the user
2. `publish_stream` permission does!
3. **NO** need for the `offline_access` permission if you want to publish on the user's own wall even if he is not online (I *guess* Facebook check if the `user_id` specified has granted your app the `publish_stream` permission and the call is issued from an allowed domain)!
4. Now if you want to publish on the user's friend wall `friend_id/feed` on a later stage (the  user is not online or currently logged-in to your app a.k.a no *valid* `access_token`) then I *think* it's **needed** to ask for the `offline_access` permission to append the user's **stored** `access_token` that was retrieved earlier by your app authentication-flow.